# chrome extension that count the number of times we visit a page

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking around for an extension that count the number I visit a site daily, and I have edited an extension from store and it work perfectly
But the problem is when I put that site into an iframe, it's not counting anymore, somebody plz take a look and give me some advice here? many thanks

manifest.json

```js
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": true,
      "scripts": [ "jquery.js", "counter.js", "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "counter.html"
   },
   "description": "Counter",
   "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAgrQn46/0KFBVFH0l9mKUXPOns5h0YMQ0isRXkB/GzK1h8JfvILDuxkIC7jbyePzMgbY0b8TO7L7FR3m4qcnPJZemz2yrGnHOkppaOWaAuyJm2cQeOul89qNPsC1GROoKfBmajag5OaOr02y4de3MEKSTubtjlO5crbg8xKnp7nHbqkeIq9MOMsEo0/uOQMqvixMnIAfPamUPOQfqmG2lUeo9UgTUoFBaxpf5VhgcuDcLHnkkSrzRrL0DoYeYFqyXwGmiCdvmwkWF+Eax/+s2xGemqMSUj0mrMxzz8KfoWuAWn9pcXYMEINSelIwS/x+wf+NWWmsCY0pV9yF54+vprQIDAQAB",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "counter",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "history", "background", "webNavigation", "http://*/*", "activeTab" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "0.4"
}
```

counter.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Display day count
  $('.day-count').text(countForToday());

  // Display yesterday count
  var yesterdayToday = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date(yesterdayToday.setDate(yesterdayToday.getDate() - 1));
  var yesterdayString = dateStringForDate(yesterday);
  var yesterdayCount = countForDay(yesterdayString);
  $('.yesterday-count').text(yesterdayCount);

  // Display last 7 days
  var weeklyTotal = countForDaysFromToday(7);
  $('.week-count').text(weeklyTotal);  

  // Display last 28 days
  var monthlyTotal = countForDaysFromToday(28);
  $('.month-count').text(monthlyTotal);

  // Total
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    if (key.indexOf("dayCount") > -1) {
      var entry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      total += entry.length;
    }
  }
  $('.all-count').text(total);

  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: '#3BAFDA' });  

}); 

function countForToday() {
  // Display day count
  var today = new Date();  
  var todayString = dateStringForDate(today);
  var todayCount = countForDay(todayString);
  return todayCount;
}

function appendUrlForDay(pageUrl, dateString) {
  // get
  var currentUrls = urlsForDay(dateString);
  // append
  var found = false;
  for(var i = 0; i < currentUrls.length; i++) {
    if (currentUrls[i] == pageUrl) {
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    currentUrls.push(pageUrl);
  }
  // set
  localStorage.setItem("dayCount-" + dateString, JSON.stringify(currentUrls));
}

function dateStringForDate(dateObj) {
  var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
  var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
  var dateString = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
  return dateString;
}

function countForDaysFromToday(number_of_days) {
  console.log(number_of_days);
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < number_of_days; i++) {
    var today = new Date();  
    var dayToLookup = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - i));
    var dayString = dateStringForDate(dayToLookup);
    var dayCount = countForDay(dayString);
    total += dayCount;
  }
  return total;
}

function urlsForDay(dateString) {
  var item = localStorage.getItem("dayCount-" + dateString);  
  return JSON.parse(item);
}

function countForDay(dateString) {
  var currentUrls = urlsForDay(dateString);
  if (currentUrls != null) {
    return currentUrls.length;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }  
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {  

  // Get chrome history
  chrome.history.search({text: '', maxResults: 1}, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(page) {
      var dateObj = new Date(page.lastVisitTime);
      var dateString = dateStringForDate(dateObj);

      // Display last page visit
      var pageUrl = page.url;

      // Set value to 0 on first load
      if (localStorage.getItem("dayCount-" + dateString) === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("dayCount-" + dateString, JSON.stringify([]));
      }

      // Check if last page contains mysite.com
      if (pageUrl.indexOf("mysite.com") > -1) {
        appendUrlForDay(pageUrl, dateString);        
      }
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: countForToday().toString() });
    });
 });

});
```

Comment: How about counting how many times `iframe` tag is loaded using jquery like `var timesLoaded = 0; $("iframe").load(function(){ timesLoaded++;}); `

Comment: And what's wrong with using [chrome.history API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history) and simply read the number of visits stored by the browser in a daily invoked [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms) callback?

Comment: ...as a sidenote, you *chrome.tabs.onUpdated* will call history multiple times for every tab update. you need to filter it with eg. changeinfo.url or something like that...

Comment: The code above get the current url of a page and count exactly how many times a given url was called (even transferred). Honestly I dont know how to deal with your suggestion here, I'm not a coder, just try to edit this extension to make it work with a site that embeded into an iframe, is it possible for me? ..

Answer (score 0):

By default, your content script will only run in the top frame of a page.  If you want it to run for all frames, you have to set all_frames to true in your manifest.

Google documents this here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts (just search for all_frames on the page).

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm follow your instruction with the code below but it seems it's not working, did I do anything wrong? or this can not make extension read the current url of iframe page to execute?



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

`code`

    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["http://example.com/*"],
          "js": ["jquery.js", "counter.js","background.js"],
          "all_frames": true
        }
      ],

Comment: you *really*'need to put your coder hat as this is what s.o. is for and about. fully understand the code and what it does. if you are counting when the onupdated url changes that will never find iframes.